# Design pattern for copy and paste on table cell

Tags: tables

I need to copy user's address from one row and apply to all or individuals. Is there any design pattern for it.

My problem is how to select the rows? should it be contextual? is there any working tool?

Comment: In what way does your application differ from a regular spreadsheet program such as Excel? Sounds very similar to me. It would definitely help if you could show a mockup of the layout.

Comment: It is a web application so there wont be any right click menu option.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a SHIFT or CTRL select to select multiple cells. I have only seen batch select on rows of data in a table, so I would refrain from adding checkboxes everywhere to select cells.

For copying/pasting you can use a keyboard shortcut, right-click context menu, a floating action menu that appears only on selected cell or a menu bar where you place the actions.

[image: selecting, copying, pasting cells]

Comment: Thanks Nash, but i don't want to override right click as it has different purpose on web, such as coping text. Also, Why did you say that you will refrain from using check boxes? It allows users to select all or a random order. (I am more inclined towards check boxes as it is widely used pattern and mental modal as well.

Comment: Copying Text? Isn't that what you want to do? Google sheets and other web applications use a right click context menu, so I think it is not such a big No-Go as a lot of people think.
Checkboxes: Why I would refrain from using checkboxes. 1. You already have a selection in a spreadsheet. The blue borders. Not that obvious but they work. 2. To make a flexible cell selection you would have to put a checkbox in every cell which clutters the UI.